# how to select row one by one and find minimum value in each row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

i have array **A** of 9x9 dimension. I want to select particular rows e.g. 2,5 ,6  and 7 and calculate minimum values in each row.

I tried

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

A.min(axis=1)

`array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])`

but it gives values for all rows simultaneosly. i want for particular rows only.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: `df.min(axis=1)`  but it gives minimum value for all rows. i want for particular rows only

Comment: What is df structure? You need to provide more information to get help.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is a NumPy array with `dh.shape == (9, 9)`, to get minimum values larger than zero, you can e.g. do

```
row2 = df[2]  # or df[2, :] to choose all columns explicitly
min2 = np.min(row2[row2 > 0])
row5 = df[5]  # or df[5, :] to choose all columns explicitly
min5 = np.min(row5[row5 > 0])
...
```

Comment: it should exclude zero.. i mean select minimum number from values >0

Answer (score 0):

Then we need to make some changes.

```
min_nums = []
for rows in matrix:
    rows = [y for y in rows if y > 0] ## If you want to include negative numbers then replace ">" with "!="
    min_nums.append(min(rows))
```

where min_nums is a list of minimum from given rows and matrix will be your given matrix. (2,5,6,7 are the indices of rows in matrix)

Comment: it should exclude zero.. i mean select minimum number from values >0

Comment: Now it will do :)

Answer (score 0):

With an array, select the desired rows by indexing, and apply `min`:

```
In [16]: x=np.arange(81).reshape(9,9)
In [17]: idx=[2,5,6,7]
In [18]: x[idx,:].min(axis=1)
Out[18]: array([18, 45, 54, 63])
In [19]: x[idx,:]
Out[19]: 
array([[18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
       [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62],
       [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71]])
```